# Bundle types with npm package from declaration files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks

I am trying to create my first npm module, here is the source code:

https://github.com/balazsorban44/use-form

I would like to use `semantic-release` and write my code in `.js` files, but I also include some type declaration files for a better experience in IDEs like VSCode. (Note, I am learning TypeScript as well)

I found a way to bundle my code and even publish it to npm with semantic-release, but when I try to import that module into a React project, I don't get any suggestions from the IDE, probably because I missed a (or a few) step(s)? How can I include the `.d.ts` files, so my IDE will pick up the type declarations?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out, thanks to the help I got on Twitter!

In `package.json` I had to add my typings folder to the files to be published on NPM:

https://github.com/balazsorban44/use-form/blob/c4e7efdbb7ca58a3ad48516e3ec63b4a71b72446/package.json#L46-L49

Apart from that, these lines may play an important role also:

https://github.com/balazsorban44/use-form/blob/c4e7efdbb7ca58a3ad48516e3ec63b4a71b72446/package.json#L18-L20